# SQLite database table updating all but one field

Tags: java, android, sqlite

So I'm working on an Android app where I have data saved in Android's SQLite database. For some reason, streakCategory and daysKept will update fine, but streakName will not update. Does anybody have any idea why? My code is the same as it is for streakCategory and daysKept.

**Snippet of EditStreak.java**:

```
doneButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            editor.putString("currButtonActivityName", streakIcon.getText().toString()).commit();
            editor.putString("currButtonActivityCategory", categoryIcon.getText().toString()).commit();
            editor.putInt("currButtonDaysKept", Integer.parseInt(streakDaysKept.getText().toString().trim())).commit();
            String updateName = prefs.getString("currButtonActivityName", "").trim();
            String updateCategory = prefs.getString("currButtonActivityCategory", "").trim();
            int updateDaysKept = prefs.getInt("currButtonDaysKept", 0);
            boolean isUpdated = db.updateData(updateName, updateCategory, updateDaysKept);
            Log.d("Name: ", prefs.getString("currButtonActivityName", ""));
            if (isUpdated == true){
                Log.d("carter.streakly", "AFTER SUCCESS: ID: " + prefs.getInt("currButtonID", 0) + " Name: " + prefs.getString("currButtonActivityName", "") + " Category: " +
                    prefs.getString("currButtonActivityCategory", "") + " Days Kept: " + prefs.getInt("currButtonDaysKept", 9));
                Intent intent = new Intent(EditStreak.this, EnlargedActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(EditStreak.this, "Data not Updated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            }
        }
    });
```

**DatabaseHelper.java**

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "streaks.db"; // Name of DB
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "streak_table";
public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
public static final String COL_2 = "STREAKNAME";
public static final String COL_3 = "STREAKCATEGORY";
public static final String COL_4 = "DATESTARTED";
public static final String COL_5 = "DAYSKEPT";

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,STREAKNAME TEXT,STREAKCATEGORY TEXT,DATESTARTED TEXT,DAYSKEPT INTEGER);");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}

public boolean insertData(String STREAKNAME, String STREAKCATEGORY, String DATESTARTED, int DAYSKEPT){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_2, STREAKNAME);
    contentValues.put(COL_3, STREAKCATEGORY);
    contentValues.put(COL_4, DATESTARTED);
    contentValues.put(COL_5, DAYSKEPT);
    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    if(result == -1){
        return false;
    } else {
        db.close();
        return true;
    }
}

public Cursor getAllData(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_NAME,null);
    return res;
}

public boolean updateData(String streakName, String streakCategory, int daysKept){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_2, streakName);
    contentValues.put(COL_3, streakCategory);
    contentValues.put(COL_5, daysKept);
    db.update(TABLE_NAME, contentValues, "STREAKNAME = ?", new String[] {streakName});
    return true;
}

public Integer deleteData(String streakName){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    return db.delete(TABLE_NAME, "STREAKNAME = ?", new String[] {streakName});
}

public boolean vacuum(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("VACUUM");
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: have you tested with rawQuery

Comment: I have not, how would I go about doing that? I'm very new to SQLite

Comment: is your issue solved?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this :

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
db.beginTransaction();
SQLiteStatement upd=db.compileStatement("UPDATE "+TABLE_NAME+" SET "+COLUMN_NAME+"=VALUE WHERE "+STREAKNAME +"=?");
upd.bindString(1, streakNameValue);
upd.execute();
db.setTransactionSuccessful();
db.endTransaction();
Log.e("update", "done");
```

Answer (score 0):

Would that ever change according to logic ?? 
you are querying the record based on streakName and updating the same name.

```
      ......
        contentValues.put(COL_2, streakName); // streakName = "abcd"
        ......      
        db.update(TABLE_NAME, contentValues, "STREAKNAME = ?", new String[] {streakName});      
            return true;
// here you are querying records which have streakName as "abcd" already, so it wont change
```

Eithe you need to change it to query it by id of record or pass old streakname which has to be replaced by this new streakName.

```
db.update(TABLE_NAME, contentValues, "STREAKID = ?", new String[] {streakID});
        return true;
```

or

```
contentValues.put(COL_2, NEWstreakName);

db.update(TABLE_NAME, contentValues, "STREAKNAME = ?", new String[] {OLDStreakName});
        return true;
```